# Segmentation Fault 11, C

Tags: c, memory-management

I've been trying to implement a `LinkedList` in C to practically implement the theory I have learnt in C. I keep getting a `Segmentation fault: 11.` Any help on how to fix this issue would be highly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Element {
    int value;
    struct Element *nextElement;
};

struct LinkedList {
    struct Element *firstElement;   
};

void add(struct LinkedList *list, int value) {
    if(list->firstElement == NULL) {
        struct Element *newElement;
        newElement = malloc(sizeof(struct Element));

        newElement->value = value;

        list->firstElement = newElement;
    } else {
        struct Element *lastElement;

        lastElement = list->firstElement;

        while(lastElement->nextElement != NULL) {
            lastElement = lastElement->nextElement;   
        }

        struct Element *newElement;
        newElement = malloc(sizeof(struct Element));

        newElement->value = value;

        lastElement->nextElement = newElement;
    }
}

void showAllElements(struct LinkedList *list) {
    struct Element *lastElement = list->firstElement;

    while(lastElement != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", lastElement->value);
        lastElement = lastElement->nextElement;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct LinkedList list;
    add(&list, 5);
    add(&list, 10);
    add(&list, 15);
    showAllElements(&list);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: check with gdb first.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Could you please tell me what gdb is?

Comment: Every memory you allocate using `malloc` should be freed with `free`. So you need to manage the memory yourself, that is do the bookkeeping and making sure no memory is leaking. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Common_errors

Comment: gdb is a debugger. if you use another debugger please use this and post its output

Comment: list->firstElement is undefined ( uninitialised ) first time add runs

Comment: @ItamarKatz Since, they are not deleted, should they still be free'd?

Comment: @amdixon I do not use any debugger. I am basically using the Xcode C compiler and brackets to write C code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'deleted'? Anyway the answer is YES.

Comment: @amdixon Oh, how do you initialise that? Do I just call the `firstElement` in the struct and give it a value of 0?

Comment: its time to learn the xcode debugger  ( lldb ) : **[debugging with lldb](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html)**

Comment: @ItamarKatz By deleted I mean, removing an element from the LinkedList. So, even if I don't remove an element from the LinkedList, I have to free the memory? If so, how would I do it when the program is done executing?

Comment: @amdixon I tried to write C in Xcode, but there is no option for it. So I'm using Brackets instead.

Comment: doesnt matter what tool you use - all will allow you to compile with debug flags at which point you can use your local debugger

Comment: Update: even after initialising the `firstElement`, it still gives me the problem.

Comment: @amdixon I am compiling through the terminal, not an IDE.

Comment: right there are probably also other problems ( hence the debugger )

Comment: Guys, can we move on to a chat instead of talking here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94522/discussion-between-amdixon-and-hassan-althaf).

Comment: For the downvoter: Please state your reason for the downvote.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf I don't know, but I suspect the downvote reason is, you didn't include the line where the segfault happens. You can get this by using debugger to get stack trace AKA backtrace when segfault happens. In this case it would probably have shown a line where you derefence `->nextElement`, which would have led you to check if `nextElement` is always initialized properly, and you would have noticed that hey, it's not.

Comment: I see.. i didnt know about debugging for C. I'm new to this.

Comment: If you cannot debug, you cannot develop software and should stop trying.   Attempts to outsource all debugging to SO, as you tried here, will always get a downvote and closevote from me.

Comment: @MartinJames "Try, try, try and one day you will fly" is a popular proverb you might have heard, which is what I have followed. I'm from an environment of much more modern languages than `C` and I started learning `C` just yesterday, therefore, I am very new. You cannot learn everything in a day I believe, a person gradually learns everything, and so will I learn how to debug C code, but first, knowing the language is more important. Peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a couple of issues with your code. `struct LinkedList list` is not assigned. It will fault when you do `list->firstElement`. Initialize it with

`struct LinkedList list = {NULL}`

Also `newElement` doesn't assign `nextElement`. You need to set it to `NULL` as well or it will fault on that access.

```
    struct Element *newElement;
    newElement = malloc(sizeof(struct Element));

    newElement->value = value;
    newElement->nextElement = NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution.